# Bootstrap column next line doesnt work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

on mobile testing something goes wrong I try it with Mobile/Responsive Web design tester,because of CoffeeCoffeeCoffeeCoffee text my colum doesnt come under my column .Here is the picture :

[image]

Here is html code :

```
 <div class="row ">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="searchable-container"> 
                        <div class="items col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 text-center">
                            <div class="info-block block-info clearfix">
                                <div class="square-box pull-left">
                                    <span class="fa fa-tags"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group bizmoduleselect">
                                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                                        <div class="bizcontent">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="var_id[]" autocomplete="off" value="">
                                            <span class="fa fa-check "></span>
                                            <h5>CoffeeCoffeeCoffeeCoffee</h5>
                                        </div>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="items col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 text-center">
                            <div class="info-block block-info clearfix">
                                <div class="square-box pull-left">
                                    <span class="fa fa-tags"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group bizmoduleselect">
                                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                                        <div class="bizcontent">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="var_id[]" autocomplete="off" value="">
                                            <span class="fa fa-check "></span>
                                            <h5>Tea</h5>
                                        </div>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="items col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 text-center ">
                            <div class="info-block block-info clearfix">
                                <div class="square-box pull-left">
                                    <span class="fa fa-tags"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group bizmoduleselect">
                                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                                        <div class="bizcontent">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="var_id[]" autocomplete="off" value="">
                                            <span class="fa fa-check "></span>
                                            <h5>Fruit Juice</h5>
                                        </div>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="items col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 text-center">
                            <div class="info-block block-info clearfix">
                                <div class="square-box pull-left">
                                    <span class="fa fa-tags"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group bizmoduleselect">
                                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                                        <div class="bizcontent">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="var_id[]" autocomplete="off" value="">
                                            <span class="fa fa-check "></span>
                                            <h5>Fruit Juice</h5>
                                        </div>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have this css for my buttons .I use bootstrap-v3.3.7.css and Bootstrap v3.3.7  js

```
label.btn-default {
        white-space: normal;
        word-break: break-all;
    }
```

Thank you for helping. !

Answer (score 0):

You could either have everything within the "row" or you could use the clear fix (https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/clearfix/)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var h = $('.items').height();
    $(".items").css("height", h+10);
});
```

*height();*    gives me the heightest column height and then I give them all this height.